# Sprite Kit - Character and Power Up Collision / Contact Detection without changing direction of Character

Tags: c#, ios7, xamarin.ios, xamarin, sprite-kit

I'm writing a physics based game using Sprite Kit. I am able to handle the contact between the main character and a power up. The power up is removed from the screen, my model is updated and the sound is played, just as expected.  However, the character changes direction when it contacts the power up. This is not desired. I'm wanting to have the character pass right through the power up and not have it's course altered by the collision.  Here is some of my code, let me know if you need more to help out.

All of this is written for Xamarin.iOS in C#. But the code is almost identical to it's Objective-C counter part.  Let me know if I need to explain any further. And thank you in advance for your help!

**Edit:** Also, this is in reference to the game I'm building discussed in this question:

[Sprite Kit - Create arch path for SKSpriteNode given a swipe gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939135/sprite-kit-create-arch-path-for-skspritenode-given-a-swipe-gesture)

** To the code! **

My collision bits enum:

```
    public enum COLLISION_BITS : uint
    {
        Character = 1 << 0,
        Background = 1 << 1,
        Ground = 1 << 2,
        BadGuy = 1 << 3,
        PowerUp = 1 << 4,
        Fan = 1 << 5
    }
```

My Character object setup:

```
    public Character (SizeF size, PointF position) : base("character")
    {
        this.Name = CHARACTER_NAME;
        this.Size = size;
        this.Position = position;
        this.PhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.BodyWithRectangleOfSize (this.Size);
        this.PhysicsBody.Dynamic = true;
        this.PhysicsBody.AffectedByGravity = true;
        this.PhysicsBody.AllowsRotation = false;
        this.PhysicsBody.Mass = 1.0f;
        this.PhysicsBody.SetCategoryBitMask (COLLISION_BITS.Character);
        this.PhysicsBody.SetContactTestBitMask (COLLISION_BITS.Ground);
        this.PhysicsBody.SetContactTestBitMask (COLLISION_BITS.BadGuy, false);
        this.PhysicsBody.SetContactTestBitMask (COLLISION_BITS.PowerUp, false);
        this.PhysicsBody.SetContactTestBitMask (COLLISION_BITS.Fan, false);
    }
```

My PowerUp object setup:

```
    private void SetupPowerUp(SizeF size, PointF position)
    {
        this.Size = size;
        this.Position = position;

        this.PhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.BodyWithRectangleOfSize (this.Size);
        this.PhysicsBody.Dynamic = false;
        this.PhysicsBody.AffectedByGravity = false;
        this.PhysicsBody.AllowsRotation = false;
        this.PhysicsBody.Mass = 0f;
        this.PhysicsBody.SetCategoryBitMask (COLLISION_BITS.PowerUp);
    }
```

My extension method that I put the bit handling in:

```
    public static void SetContactTestBitMask(this SKPhysicsBody body, COLLISION_BITS bits, bool overwrite = true)
    {
        if (body == null) return;

        if (overwrite) {
            body.ContactTestBitMask = (uint)bits;
        } else {
            body.ContactTestBitMask |= (uint)bits;
        }
    }

    public static void SetCategoryBitMask(this SKPhysicsBody body, COLLISION_BITS bits, bool overwrite = true)
    {
        if (body == null) return;

        if (overwrite) {
            body.CategoryBitMask = (uint)bits;
        } else {
            body.CategoryBitMask |= (uint)bits;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsOfCategory(this SKPhysicsBody body, COLLISION_BITS bits, bool matchAll = false)
    {
        if (body == null) return false;

        if (matchAll) {
            return (body.CategoryBitMask & (uint)bits) == (uint)bits;
        } else {
            return (body.CategoryBitMask & (uint)bits) > 0;
        }
    }
```

And lastly, my DidBeginContact method:

```
    public void HandleDidBeginContact(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        var contact = (SKPhysicsContact)sender;
        SKPhysicsBody firstBody, secondBody;

        if (contact.BodyA.CategoryBitMask < contact.BodyB.CategoryBitMask) {
            firstBody = contact.BodyA;
            secondBody = contact.BodyB;
        } else {
            firstBody = contact.BodyB;
            secondBody = contact.BodyA;
        }

        // collected power up
        if (firstBody.IsOfCategory(COLLISION_BITS. Character) && secondBody.IsOfCategory(COLLISION_BITS.PowerUp)) {

            secondBody.Node.RemoveFromParent ();
            GameModel.GatheredPowerUp ();
            PowerUpCollisionSoundPlayer.Play ();
        }

        // other collision stuff for the other objects in the screen...
        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the category and contact callback bit masks, but you don't seem to be setting the `collisionBitMask` - it's kept at its default value, so your character is set to collide with anything and changing direction on contact.

Try setting the player's collision bit mask explicitly (probably `this.PhysicsBody.setCollisionBitMask` in Xamarin?), stating all categories that this player should make a physical collision with, and omitting the categories it should pass through (PowerUp).

Comment: Perfect, that was it. My assumption that the default value of the collisionBitMask was it would not collide with anything at all. Still a bit confused about the differences of the collisionBitMask and the contactTestBitMask though. But this helped me get it working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are **3 properties** of `SKPhysicsBody`.

`categoryBitMask` *property*
`collisionBitMask` *property*
`contactTestBitMask` *property*

In your case, you want a **logical collision**  an **not a physical collision**.
So, like you did, you need to set the `contactTestBitMask` but you also need to set the `collisionBitMask` to the `categoryBitMask` of your object and both `SKPhysicsBody` to dynamic (`this.PhysicsBody.Dynamic = true;` but it is the default value so you can ignore it).

I wrote you the simple construction code (it is more understandable) but you can adapt it to your structure (with internals/externals methods).

Collision bits enum:

```
public enum COLLISION_BITS : uint
{
    Character = 1 << 0,
    Background = 1 << 1,
    Ground = 1 << 2,
    BadGuy = 1 << 3,
    PowerUp = 1 << 4,
    Fan = 1 << 5
}
```

Character object setup:

```
public Character (SizeF size, PointF position) : base("character")
{
     this.Name = CHARACTER_NAME;
     this.Size = size;
     this.Position = position;
     this.PhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.BodyWithRectangleOfSize (this.Size);
     this.PhysicsBody.AffectedByGravity = true;
     this.PhysicsBody.AllowsRotation = false;
     this.PhysicsBody.Mass = 1.0f;
     this.PhysicsBody.CategoryBitMask = COLLISION_BITS.Character;
     this.PhysicsBody.CollisionBitMask = COLLISION_BITS.Character;
     this.PhysicsBody.ContactTestBitMask = COLLISION_BITS.PowerUp;
}
```

PowerUp object setup:

```
private void SetupPowerUp(SizeF size, PointF position)
{
    this.Size = size;
    this.Position = position;

    this.PhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.BodyWithRectangleOfSize (this.Size);
    this.PhysicsBody.AffectedByGravity = false;
    this.PhysicsBody.AllowsRotation = false;
    this.PhysicsBody.Mass = 0f;
    this.PhysicsBody.CategoryBitMask = COLLISION_BITS.PowerUp;
    this.PhysicsBody.CollisionBitMask = COLLISION_BITS.PowerUp;
    this.PhysicsBody.ContactTestBitMask = COLLISION_BITS.Character;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer and code. It was great to learn about the different types of collisions (logical vs. physical).